# Rails Hyperlink not affected by CSS

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, blogs

I'm building a simple rails blog and trying to spice it up at the moment with some CSS.

I can't for the life of me change the Link Headings with any of my CSS. I even surrounded it with a Div ID and tried it that way to no avail. Its probably something simple that I'm missing here but I cannot find out what that is. Here's the code in question.

```
<div id="article-header"><h2><%= link_to article.title, article_path(article) %></h2></div>
```

Heres my CSS stylesheet

```
    .bit-25 {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #999999;
  color: #606e67;
  float: right;
  display: block;
}

.bit-75 {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #999999;
  color: #606e67;
}


.clearfooter {
  height: 330px;
  clear: both;
}


footer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 330px;
  background: #3f4944;
}



html,body {
  background: #efeddf;
  height: 100%;
}


#article-header {
  color: #555;
}

#main-header {
  height: 140px;
  background: #57645d;  
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 100000;
  width: 100%;

}


#main-nav ul {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 120px;
  padding-top: 
}

#main-nav ul li {
  padding-left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

#main-nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #efeddf;
}
```

I'm using a grid system called lemonade in case anyone is confused by the .bit classes. I'm a newbie at all this so while I enjoy it, any criticisms at all are welcome.:)

Comment: Add the `id` to the `h2` itself, not the surrounding div? And make sure your css is included in the page. You can also right click on the element in your browser and select "Inspect Element" (or similar depending on your browser). It will open the dev console. On the right, you should be able to see the styles that apply to your element.

Comment: Tried that Robin, to no avail. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: The framework might be overriding your style with a style that has more priority (which seems weird but...). Open the console, and look at the styles of your h2. Check if your styles for the h2 appear.

Comment: Ok, so I figured it out. It was an issue with the Ruby code. The "link_to" translates to an "a" element. The CSS was completely missing the element because I had "#article-header" instead of "#article-header a" I saw it when I "inspected element" thanks to your suggestion. Thanks for all the suggestions and help everyone. I'm always pleasantly surprised with the promptness in which people are willing to help out with any issue on here. It seems I cant check an answer here since yours appears to be a comment.

Comment: I added an answer. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cases like these, the dev console is really helpful, and allows you to inspect elements and their CSS.

Right click on an element and click "Inspect Element", in Chrome or Firefox.

Here, you discovered that you had to restyle the color of the link within the h2 (`h2 a`), instead of the `h2`.

Comment: Thanks, definitely going to take advantage of this tool more.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing a value for the `padding-top` property in the `#main-nav ul` selector. That cascades the error down to properties below it. Try putting a value there or removing it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Didn't fix my main issue but I hadn't noticed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to override the pseudo classes for the a element:

```
#main-nav ul li a:link, a:active, a:hover, a:visited,  {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #efeddf;
}
```

Check out http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-class-selectors/.

Comment: Thanks. That didn't work but its nice to know about those options. Will certainly use in the future.